# Парсинг BeautifulSoup как спарсить элементы имеющие один класс и не имеющие другого?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Как спарсить *item* не спарсив при этом *item title* используя BeautifulSoup?

```
<div class="item title">
    <span class="letter"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a class="link" href="">
        <span class="title"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a class="link" href="">
        <span class="title"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте так - tags_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "item"})

Comment: Нет, все равно выводит одно и тоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующий образом, в цикле смотрю есть ли у класса значения *item* и *title*, если есть пропускаю, если нет значит у класса только значение *item*

```
items = soup.find_all("div", class_="item")

for item in items:
    if item.get("class") == ['item', 'title']:
        continue
    ...
```

Comment: или if 'title' in item.get("class"): continue